# How to insert list in a precise line in file

Tags: python, file, line

I need to unzip a folder and update several lines in a file called "main.py". For context, this .zip file will be used to create a Lambda with Terraform.

I'm being able to unzip the folder and I'm being able to update the lines of code in "main.py" file (the changes I apply to these lines are in another file, "conditions.txt". Those changes are the ID's of some alerts in a policy of NewRelic).

My problem is that when I insert the lines back into the file they go to the end of the file. Even though I know precisely that the new lines (from 20 to 22 of them, depending on the "conditions.txt" file) should be inserted starting on line 8 of "main.py" file, I'm not being able to do so.
I've tried many things but the result is always the same. I feel I'm missing something, and  I can't find a solution online.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Here is the python code I'm running, after that I included the code of "main.py" file:

```
import zipfile

# unzip the file in "temp" folder (works fine)
with zipfile.ZipFile("Archive.zip", 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall("temp")

# delete "payload_" lines that will later be replaced
with open("temp/main.py", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open("temp/main.py", "w") as f:
    for line in lines:

        # if the line in the file does not start with "payload_" its re-writen
        if not line.lstrip().startswith("payload_"):
            f.write(line)


# take "conditions" file and create the text to be inserted in "main.py" inside "temp" folder
conditions = open("conditions.txt").readlines()
condition = ""

new_payload_lines = []

for index, condition in enumerate(conditions):
    index = index + 1
    condition = condition.replace(",", "")
    condition = condition.strip()

    new_payload_lines.append('payload_%s="{\\"query\\":\\"mutation {\\\\n    alertsNrqlConditionStaticUpdate(id: %s, accountId: 11111111, condition: {\\\\n        enabled : true\\\\n      }) {\\\\n        name\\\\n    }\\\\n}\\\\n\\",\\"variables\\":{}}"' % (index, condition))


# This inserts the lines in "new_payload_lines" with proper format, but at the end of the file, which is wrong
with open("temp/main.py", "r+") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):

        if line.startswith("url"):
            f.write("\n")
            for payload in new_payload_lines:
                f.write(payload + "\n")
```

This is the file I'm trying to modify, "main.py". You can see the "payload_x" lines that I need to replace:

```
from ast import For
import requests
import json

url = "https://api.newrelic.com/graphql"


payload_1="{\"query\":\"mutation {\\n    alertsNrqlConditionStaticUpdate(id: 27058756, accountId: 1111111, condition: {\\n        enabled : true\\n      }) {\\n        name\\n    }\\n}\\n\",\"variables\":{}}"
payload_2="{\"query\":\"mutation {\\n    alertsNrqlConditionStaticUpdate(id: 27058757, accountId: 1111111, condition: {\\n        enabled : true\\n      }) {\\n        name\\n    }\\n}\\n\",\"variables\":{}}"
payload_3="{\"query\":\"mutation {\\n    alertsNrqlConditionStaticUpdate(id: 27058758, accountId: 1111111, condition: {\\n        enabled : true\\n      }) {\\n        name\\n    }\\n}\\n\",\"variables\":{}}"
payload_4="{\"query\":\"mutation {\\n    alertsNrqlConditionStaticUpdate(id: 27058759, accountId: 1111111, condition: {\\n        enabled : true\\n      }) {\\n        name\\n    }\\n}\\n\",\"variables\":{}}"
payload_5="{\"query\":\"mutation {\\n    alertsNrqlConditionStaticUpdate(id: 27058760, accountId: 1111111, condition: {\\n        enabled : true\\n      }) {\\n        name\\n    }\\n}\\n\",\"variables\":{}}"
payload_6="{\"query\":\"mutation {\\n    alertsNrqlConditionStaticUpdate(id: 27058761, accountId: 1111111, condition: {\\n        enabled : true\\n      }) {\\n        name\\n    }\\n}\\n\",\"variables\":{}}"
payload_7="{\"query\":\"mutation {\\n    alertsNrqlConditionStaticUpdate(id: 27058762, accountId: 1111111, condition: {\\n        enabled : true\\n      }) {\\n        name\\n    }\\n}\\n\",\"variables\":{}}"
payload_8="{\"query\":\"mutation {\\n    alertsNrqlConditionStaticUpdate(id: 27058763, accountId: 1111111, condition: {\\n        enabled : true\\n      }) {\\n        name\\n    }\\n}\\n\",\"variables\":{}}"
payload_9="{\"query\":\"mutation {\\n    alertsNrqlConditionStaticUpdate(id: 27058764, accountId: 1111111, condition: {\\n        enabled : true\\n      }) {\\n        name\\n    }\\n}\\n\",\"variables\":{}}"
payload_10="{\"query\":\"mutation {\\n    alertsNrqlConditionStaticUpdate(id: 27058765, accountId: 1111111, condition: {\\n        enabled : true\\n      }) {\\n        name\\n    }\\n}\\n\",\"variables\":{}}"
payload_11="{\"query\":\"mutation {\\n    alertsNrqlConditionStaticUpdate(id: 27058766, accountId: 1111111, condition: {\\n        enabled : true\\n      }) {\\n        name\\n    }\\n}\\n\",\"variables\":{}}"
payload_12="{\"query\":\"mutation {\\n    alertsNrqlConditionStaticUpdate(id: 27058767, accountId: 1111111, condition: {\\n        enabled : true\\n      }) {\\n        name\\n    }\\n}\\n\",\"variables\":{}}"
payload_13="{\"query\":\"mutation {\\n    alertsNrqlConditionStaticUpdate(id: 27058768, accountId: 1111111, condition: {\\n        enabled : true\\n      }) {\\n        name\\n    }\\n}\\n\",\"variables\":{}}"
payload_14="{\"query\":\"mutation {\\n    alertsNrqlConditionStaticUpdate(id: 27058769, accountId: 1111111, condition: {\\n        enabled : true\\n      }) {\\n        name\\n    }\\n}\\n\",\"variables\":{}}"
payload_15="{\"query\":\"mutation {\\n    alertsNrqlConditionStaticUpdate(id: 27058770, accountId: 1111111, condition: {\\n        enabled : true\\n      }) {\\n        name\\n    }\\n}\\n\",\"variables\":{}}"
payload_16="{\"query\":\"mutation {\\n    alertsNrqlConditionStaticUpdate(id: 27058772, accountId: 1111111, condition: {\\n        enabled : true\\n      }) {\\n        name\\n    }\\n}\\n\",\"variables\":{}}"
payload_17="{\"query\":\"mutation {\\n    alertsNrqlConditionStaticUpdate(id: 27058773, accountId: 1111111, condition: {\\n        enabled : true\\n      }) {\\n        name\\n    }\\n}\\n\",\"variables\":{}}"
payload_18="{\"query\":\"mutation {\\n    alertsNrqlConditionStaticUpdate(id: 27058774, accountId: 1111111, condition: {\\n        enabled : true\\n      }) {\\n        name\\n    }\\n}\\n\",\"variables\":{}}"
payload_19="{\"query\":\"mutation {\\n    alertsNrqlConditionStaticUpdate(id: 27058775, accountId: 1111111, condition: {\\n        enabled : true\\n      }) {\\n        name\\n    }\\n}\\n\",\"variables\":{}}"
payload_20="{\"query\":\"mutation {\\n    alertsNrqlConditionStaticUpdate(id: 27058776, accountId: 1111111, condition: {\\n        enabled : true\\n      }) {\\n        name\\n    }\\n}\\n\",\"variables\":{}}"

headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'API-Key': 'AAAA-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
}

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  
  payloads = [payload_1,payload_2,payload_3,payload_4,payload_5,payload_6,payload_7,payload_8,payload_9,payload_10,payload_11,payload_12,payload_13,payload_14,payload_15,payload_16,payload_17,payload_18,payload_19,payload_20]
  for ids in payloads:
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=ids)

  return {
      'statusCode': 200,
      'body': json.dumps('Conditions updated!')
  }
```

Comment: Try looking at [Replace a Line in a File in Python](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/python-replace-line-in-file/).

Comment: Thanks @Alias Cartellano but I've tried those solutions but I can't seem to tell my code where to put the new lines. Am I missing something?

Answer (score -1):

I just figured out a solution in case anyone else has this issue (it's ugly, but it works).

I just renamed main.py to main_new.py and made a copy the renamed file, main_new_copy.py. I left the first part of main_new.py, I deleted all the rest, just where I needed to place my updated list. Then I placed the list there with write() method.
on main_new_copy.py I wrote the second part of the file, the one I had deleted.
Then I joined the two files.
Who needs elegance when you have a deadline, lol.

This is the code:

```
import zipfile
import re
import shutil
import os


# unzip the file in "temp" folder (works fine)
with zipfile.ZipFile("Archive.zip", 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall("temp")


# RENAME FILE BEFORE COPYING IT
old_name = r"temp/main.py"
new_name = r"temp/main_new.py"


os.rename(old_name, new_name)


#COPY MAIN.PY FILE TO THEN COPY THE OTHER HALF OF IT
original = r'temp/main_new.py'
target = r'temp/main_new_copy.py'

shutil.copyfile(original, target)


# delete "payload_" lines that will later be replaced
with open("temp/main_new.py", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open("temp/main_new.py", "w") as f:

    counter = 0

    for line in lines:
        
            # THIS WILL ONLY COPY PORTION OF THE FILE BEFORE THE LIST I NEED TO INSERT
            if not line.lstrip().startswith("payload_") and counter < 7:

                f.write(line)
                counter += 1
                print(counter)
               

# take conditions file and create the text to be inserted in "main.py" inside "temp"

conditions = open("conditions.txt").readlines()

condition = ""

new_payload_lines = []

for index, condition in enumerate(conditions):
    index = index + 1
    condition = condition.replace(",", "")
    condition = condition.strip()

    new_payload_lines.append('payload_%s="{\\"query\\":\\"mutation {\\\\n    alertsNrqlConditionStaticUpdate(id: %s, accountId: 11111111, condition: {\\\\n        enabled : true\\\\n      }) {\\\\n        name\\\\n    }\\\\n}\\\\n\\",\\"variables\\":{}}"' % (index, condition))

# OPEN THE "HALF FILE" I CREATED SO I CAN WRITE THE LIST WHERE I NEED TO
with open("temp/main_new.py", "r+") as f:
    counter = 0
    payloads = old_payloads
    subs = new_payload_lines

    for line in f:

        for payload in new_payload_lines:
            f.write(payload + "\n")

# THIS OPENS THE COPY OF THE NEW FILE AND WRITES THE OTHER HALF
with open("temp/main_new_copy.py", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open("temp/main_new_copy.py", "w") as f:


    for index_2, line in enumerate(lines):
            
            # AT INDEX_2 (LINE) 28 THE TEXT I NEED STARTS, THE UPPER PART OF THE FILE IS NOT COPIED
            if index_2 >= 28:

                f.write(line)
                counter += 1

            else:
                pass

# MERGING THE TWO FILES
data = data2 = ""

with open('temp/main_new.py') as fp:
    data = fp.read()


with open('temp/main_new_copy.py') as fp:
    data2 = fp.read()

data += "\n"
data += data2

with open('temp/main.py', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write(data)

# DELETE THE NEW FILE AND ITS COPY
os.remove('temp/main_new_copy.py')
os.remove('temp/main_new.py')
```

Comment: Reading a whole file content in memory is highly discouraged. Text files are iterators. Just iterate on the file, i.e. each line, and write it to its destination file. Stop when you reach the desired line. Then iterate on the list and write each element to the destination file. Then continue iterating on the source file

Comment: Hello @Pynchia, yes I'm full aware that this is not a good solution. 
Could you add some sample code to your proposition? sounds just like what I was trying to do (and wasn't able to do)